# Oracle merge statement and by source/target condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dml, sql-merge

I need to do a `MERGE` in Oracle, but I'm stuck.

In SQL Server, I always use the `BY SOURCE` and `BY TARGET` condition to check where record exists, and then take an action.

I'm a little confused because I don't know how to achieve the same in PL/SQL.
I need to do a `MERGE` on two tables (`customers` and `customers_stage`).

- If the record does not exists in the customer table - then insert.
- If the record exits in both - then update.
- If the record does not exists in customers_stage - then delete.

In SQL Server, it would look like this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.Customers AS target
USING dbo.Customers_stage AS source ON target.ID = source.ExternalID

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
   THEN 
      INSERT

WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN
      UPDATE

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
   THEN
      DELETE
```

How to achieve the same functionality in Oracle? I use SQL Developer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Pls read this. http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_rittman_merge.htm